# What is the explicit formula for the affine map $\theta:R \rightarrow R$ carrying $[s_1, s_2] \rightarrow [b_1, b_2]$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Give an explicit formula for the affine map $\theta:R \rightarrow R$ carrying $[s_1, s_2] \rightarrow [b_1, b_2]$
>   with $\theta(s_i) = b_i$, for $i=1,2$. 
>   In particular, give a formula for the affine map taking
>   $[32, 212]$ onto $[0, 100]$. (Hint: $\theta(x) = \lambda (x) + x_0$ where $\lambda$ is a linear transformation)

I don't exactly understand what this is asking.  Isn't the affine map just $$\theta(ts_1 + (1-t)s_2) = tb_1 +(1-t)b_2$$ and therefore for the second part it would replace the specific end points into the first formula?

What's the purpose of the hint?

Comment: Yes this is the map, but it is also on the form $x \mapsto \lambda x + y$ where $\lambda$ is linear, hence the hint is not totally useless. (I don't understand what do you mean by $\sum t = 1$, neither why there is this tag "algebraic topology").

Comment: @N.H. Edited for clarity, I was implying that it was satisfying the convex combination requirements but miswrote.  And this question is from Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology.  Is there a better tag for this subject?

Comment: Ok, if it's from such book I think it's probably fine :) And as I said your map is correct but you can also do his way (i.e plugging $s_i, b_i$ in $\theta s_i + x_0 = b_i$ and solve the system. This is really the same.

Comment: @N.H. What do you mean by solving the system?  If I have $b_1 = \lambda(s_1) + x_0$ and $b_2 = \lambda(s_2) + x_0$ what would I be solving for here?

Comment: Unless you mean solve for $\lambda(1)$ and $x_0$?  Which results in $\lambda(1) = \frac{b_1-b_2}{s_1-s_2}$ and $x_0=\frac{s_1b_2-b_1s_2}{s_1-s_2}$, and therefore $\lambda(x)=x \lambda(1)$ and therefore $\theta(x) = x \frac{b_-b_2}{s_1-s_2} + \frac{s_2b_1-b_1s_2}{s_1-s_2}$?

Comment: Exactly, solve for $\lambda(1)$ and $x_0$.